# Wireguard windows client not working while android is ok

Tags: wireguard

I've configured wireguard server on my VPS:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <hidden>
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = <hidden>
PresharedKey = <hidden>
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = <hidden>
PresharedKey = <hidden>
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.3/32
```

cat /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

iptables -S

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

iptables -S -t nat

```
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And here is my client config, which work perfectly fine on Android:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <hidden>
Address = 10.8.0.3/24
DNS = 94.140.14.14, 94.140.15.15

[Peer]
PublicKey = <hidden>
PresharedKey = <hidden>
Endpoint = <hidden>:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

On windows I can only ping server (10.8.0.1), but have no internet. What am I missing?

**UPD**. By term "no internet" I mean TCP connections on port 80 and 443. Windows client send packets, but not receiving response. Same client with another wg config also working fine. So now I'm going to think that this is some strange limitation of VPS provider. Bot how it can be possible that Android client is ok, and Windows fails in the same time?

**SOLVED (KIND OF).** It turns out that adding `MTU = 1280` into client config fixes problem. Still need detailed explanation what is going on, since this is the first time I've encountered with additional wg settings.

**UPD2**. There is another problem with upload speed over VPN - it is extremely slow, about 1-2 mbit. Upload speed on server is ok, about 200 mbit. Still have no clue what is wrong with that server. Speed measured on client with VPN enabled:

```
./speedtest

   Speedtest by Ookla

     Server: ORANGE FRANCE - Paris (id = 24215)
        ISP: OVH SAS
    Latency:    95.26 ms   (4.92 ms jitter)
   Download:    77.74 Mbps (data used: 107.6 MB)
     Upload:     3.09 Mbps (data used: 3.3 MB)
Packet Loss:    69.4%
```

Comment: Routing on Windows is a lot more complex than on Unix-like systems.

Comment: By Internet, you mean you checked with public IP like `8.8.8.8`, or was it actually a DNS issue?

Comment: @TomYan by internet I mean TCP connections on port 80 and 443. Windows client send packets, but not receiving response. Same client with another wg config also working fine. Now I'm going to think that this some strange limitation of VPS provider. Bot how it can be?

Comment: https://lists.zx2c4.com/pipermail/wireguard/2017-December/002201.html Probably the MTU of the Ethernet interface on your Windows machine (or the VPS, I don't know enough to tell when/where exactly the MTU limit applies) is less than 1500 (or even 1480). As you might be aware of, 1280 is used instead of 1420 for the default MTU in the Android client.

Answer (score 1):

https://lists.zx2c4.com/pipermail/wireguard/2017-December/002201.html

As far as I know, the MTU set on the wireguard interface needs to be:

1. 60 (IPv4) / 80 (IPv6) bytes less than the MTU of the Ethernet interface on the same host that is used for the wireguard connection (the IP protocol version here refers to the one used for `Endpoint=`)
2. less than or equal to the MTU of the Ethernet interface that the decapsulated packet is forwarded through.

Whether it needs to be less than or equal to the MTU of the wireguard interface on the the the other host, or that of the Ethernet interface on that host that is used for the wireguard connection (in case it's different from 2 above), are unclear to me.

You might be able to break the packets down into fragments before (re-)encapsulation with iptables / nftables in Linux by the way. Wireguard itself provides no such facility at the moment, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Lowering the MTU solved my wireguard problem.

My wireguard problem being: I could connect to the wirguard server and I could ping URLs but when trying to browse I only got timeout errors. Very very rarely parts of a website would show up but they would not load completely. And I had this only with Windows 10. Android device on the same network worked fine.
After lowering the MTU I have no issue with upload bandwidth - it is similar to what I have without VPN - maybe 5% less - probably explained by the protocol overhead.

I tried two comercial VPN providers and had the same problem with both clients (IVPN and Proton). Proton would test wireguard and refuse to use it because "the network does not support wireguard". IVPN client will establish the connection but then browsing will not work  - until you lower the MTU manually like this:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface ivpn mtu=1340 store=persistent
```

(probably store=persistent does not help anyway)

To find out your MTU size:

```
Ping  yahoo.com -f -l 1492
```

It will repond with "packet needs to be fragmented"
Lower the number "1492" until there is no fragmentation - in my case 1340 works.

To see the configured MTU:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface
```